# I am using React Hook correctly?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I want to apply React hook for **infinite scroll**. So, I end up with this code:

```
export default function index() {
  const [allTracks, setAllTracks] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState("");

  const { tracks, error, loading, lastVisible } = useFetchPublicTracks(
    myApiEndPoint.TRENDING_TRACKS,
    5,
    offset
  );

  //concat tracks when got data successfully
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && tracks) setAllTracks([...allTracks, ...tracks]);
  }, [loading, tracks]);

  console.log("tracks", allTracks);
  console.log("lastVisible", lastVisible);
  console.log("loading", loading);

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="" onClick={() => setOffset(lastVisible)}>
        Load More
      </button>
      <Main></Main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click **"Load More"** button, new offset will be setted. After that, component re-render again and call Api with new offset.

I want ask that **I am using React hook correctly** ? There is any way better ? Also, Do I need to use **useCallback/useMemo** in my use case ?

Comment: seems to be correct for me, and only use useMemo / useCallback if you have non hook functions that you want to memoize  - in your case it seems that you don't have any.

Comment: Hooks usage looks ok. I would suggest skipping the use of useMemo / useCallback in the initial implementation. Add it once you are certain you need it. There is a good article about this by Kent C. Dodds https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback